# Remove multiple documents and pass them to the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to find the right way to remove multiple documents with the possibility to access them afterwards.

To achieve that with **one** document you can use [findByIdAndRemove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) or [findOneAndRemove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove) which both pass the found document to the callback. However I didn't find any method to accomplish that with multiple documents. So here is my current solution:

```
Model.find({}, function(err, docs){

  // do some stuff with docs
  // like removing attached uploaded files (avatars, pictures, ...)

  Model.remove({}, function(err, docs){

    // here docs only return the deleted documents' count
    // i'm unable to perform any kind of operations on docs

  })
})
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use async and underscore modules in such cases. At first i create tasks array for async and then execute them in parallel. e.g.
var async = require('async');
var _ = require('underscore');

```
Model.find({}, function(err, docs){
  // do something
  var tasks = [];
  _.each(docs, function(doc){
    tasks.push(function(callback){
      doc.remove(function(err, removedItem){
        callback(err, removedItem);
      });
    });  
  });
  async.parallel(tasks, function(err, results){
    // results now is an array of removedItems
  });
});
```

See https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel and http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove

p.s. you may replace underscore with native Array.prototype.forEach.

Comment: I'm not understanding every bit of it yet, but I have to say your solution is very interesting. I was not expecting that kind of answer, something more like `findAllAndRemove`. But anyway, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there's no findAllAndSomething which would be quite useful indeed. To simulate FindAll... you can try to use mapReduce without reduce stage. However, it sounds a little bit scary :)